# Protobuf-net unrecognized stream prefix

Tags: python, c#, protocol-buffers, reverse-engineering, protobuf-net

I'm trying to reverse engineer the Quasar RAT protobuf protocol structure. 
Quasar is a Remote Administration Tool written in C# which is open source and can be found online here.
https://github.com/quasar/QuasarRAT

I've managed to reverse most of it and I can now connect to the Quasar server client from a python script. How ever one question remains open, it appears that every byte stream that is being sent from the client to the server begins with a 3 byte field which is not registered within the protobuf class within Quasar. This field seems to provide the length of the message not including the prefixed bytes. As can be seen within this block for an example a prefixed byte stream generated for an array of size 0x2d2, these are the prefixed bytes being appended to the message.

```
0x0A, 0xCF, 0x05
```

If how ever I decide to change the message fields before serializing the message, this byte stream would change except from the first **0x0A** byte. It seems that if I keep appending bytes to the message fields the second byte grows and  if I overflow the second byte(make it reach above **0xff**) - it would increment the third byte and reset the second byte to **0x80**. But the math wont make sense to me at all as this field should return the size of the array but doesn't under any sensible formula that I could compute. I know that protobuf-net can generate **PreLengthPrefix** bytes to prefix the message with the length of it but this is not the case here.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So it isn't just a "varint"?

Comment: Can you elaborate? Perhaps I miss understood that when I was reading about the encoding. As I understood the first byte 0x0a is indicating that its a type of string?

Comment: @MarcGravell Hey, I've inspected what youve said and it seems to make sense how ever I dont understand on why the 0x0A is prefixed as it is supposed to indicate field 1 - type string

Comment: in protobuf field headers ("tags"), the 3 LSBs represent the wire type. So: take your field *number* (1) and left-shift that 3 bits, giving you binary 1000. Now combine that with the wire type of "length prefixed", which is 2 (binary 010), and you get binary 1010 - or in hex: 0A. If you have an entire payload, https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode can walk you through each piece. When deciding, obviously reverse this: `(tag & 7)` gives you the wire type, `(tag >> 3)` gives you the number. This is after varint decode, obviously.

Comment: Alright you have made it very clear, how ever how does one determine if 2 is a length prefix or a string, is it a guess the decoder has to take?

Comment: you literally cannot tell. The wire format is ambiguous and is only clear when considered alongside schema knowledge. A wire type of 2 simply means "length prefixed" - it could be a UTF-8 string, a raw binary BLOB (`bytes`), a sub-message, or a "packed array" of primitive values like integers or floating points. Without the schema: you can only speculate (which is why my decode page often lists multiple options, and even then it isn't exhaustive)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The encoding rules are here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding

Basically, each field is a encoded as a field-header (aka "tag"), followed by a payload. The field-header is a "varint" (see the encoding guide), the value of which is an integer composed of a field number and the wire-type. The wire-type is the 3 least significant bits, and the field number is the rest (shifted by 3 bits). In the case of 0x0A (binary 1010), the wire type is 2 (binary 010), and the field number is 1.

How you treat the payload depends on the wire type. For wire type 2 (length prefixed), you should expect next:

- a varint that is the length of the payload in bytes, then
- that many bytes of the actual payload

Unfortunately protobuf is ambiguous without a schema, so knowing that you have length prefixed data doesn't tell you what the data *is*; a length prefixed payload could be:

- a UTF-8 string
- a raw BLOB (`bytes`)
- a sub-message
- a "packed" array of some primitive type (integers/floating point numbers/etc) - remembering that the length prefix is the number of **bytes**, not the number of elements; the elements are not even necessarily fixed size (they could themselves be varints

---

In many ways, the purpose of the wire type isn't to tell you how to interpret the data; it is to tell you how to *skip* (or just store verbatim) the field if it isn't one you know about. For example, somebody else is using V3 of the API and you have only updated your schema to V2; they send a V3 message to your V2 API; V3 has extra fields you don't care about - the deserializer needs to not break when it hits them, so the wire type tells it *how to ignore the field* (i.e. what the rules are for finding the next field). Otherwise, we could just use the schema information and not store the wire type in the payload *at all* (although it is also used as an optimization on repeated primitive data, via "packed" arrays - it is up to the serializer whether it encodes such as length-prefixed vs lots of field header/value pairs).